# SpringMVC-router - support for static content and REST repositories

Tags: spring-mvc, router

I am trying to use springmvc-router (https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router) as I am unable to use play for my current project and would love for the routes to be better organized.

I do have a couple of questions:

1. Play supports static content routing using `staticDir` and `staticFile` - what is the alternative when using springmvc-router?
2. I am using Spring data JPA REST repositories and am trying to figure out how they should be mapped to replace the `@RestResource(path = "roles", rel = "roles")` annotation on the repositories.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
-N